# How to add input's value as a class to parent

Tags: jquery, addclass, attr

I want to take an input and use it's value as the name of a class that is added to it's parent.

So this:

```
<div class="">
    <input value="something">
</div>
```

Would turn into this:

```
<div class="something">
    <input value="something">
</div>
```

This is what I have, but it's not working:

```
$('input').parent('td').addClass($('input').attr('value'));
```

Comment: Parent `'td'`... but you have no `<td>` element as parent

Comment: There's an important distinction between *attributes* and *properties* that you may be missing. Attributes don't change as a result of user interaction with the element. Properties do. The jquery `attr` method gets attributes, so `attr('value')` will still return "something" even after the user has changed it. This is why the answers have said to use `val()`. (They also could have used `prop('value')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it; you just have to decide **when** to do it -- as in what event should trigger this code:

```
$('input').parent('div').addClass( function() {
    return $(this).find('input').val();
});
```

```js
$('input').parent('div').addClass( function() {
  return $(this).find('input').val();
});


//output new HTML
var newHTML = $('<div/>').html( $('div.something').clone() ).html();
$('pre.out').text( newHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    <input value="something">
</div>

<h1>New HTML</h1>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.parent('div')` instead of `'td'`

(you can also use the `.closest()` Method)
Also you can use `.val()` instead of `.attr()` [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/gozibi/3/edit)

```
var $input = $("input"); // Cache your selectors
$input.closest('div').addClass( $input.val() );
```